# scroll text of textArea on scroll view

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I am facing problem for scrolling text of text area.I have following structure of code for this
1-Scrollview as vertical layout.
2-On this scroll view keep a view.
3-On this view keep text Area.

In this structure the text is not scrolling smoothly.

Comment: You need to update your question with some code.

Answer (score 1):

**I think you are looking for this code.**

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerlayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomlayout"
         >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/text_aboutus"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/text_data"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textColor="#000" />



    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I need it on titanium appceleraror

Answer (score 0):

If you need horizontal scroll for text view then try this  in xml file

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
. . . .
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

If you need vertcal scroll for text view try this in your activity

```
textview.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
```